# How to make imported projects use older api level?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a relatively old android device that works under api level 15, and I want to make some simple programs for it. Right now I just watch examples. I'm importing them from the `sdk/samples/android-15` directory via the import command, they are imported as android-21 projects, then I go to module config and change api level to 15. This seemed to long for me, so I tried to fix it by deleting all sdk except 15. Now it doesn't import at all.

Where I can tell android studio to use sdk 15?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to change anything in the module configuration.

Go to your build.gradle file and check the next:

```
compileSdkVersion 21  //the version of the API the app is compiled against
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
   // put here the minimum Api version compatible, in your case 15 or lower
    minSdkVersion 15

    targetSdkVersion 21
}

dependencies {
    //be sure you add the dependencies with the support library 
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

have you enabled the developer options in your device?
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

SDK manager: Check out that you didn't delete the minimun sdk tools required:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html
You dont need to download all the api version abailable, those are

Comment: Err, is it possible to teach android studio to use api 15 on import without editing build.gradle every time? Yes, I enabled usb debugging, and debuged one app right on real device.

Comment: You should edit your gradle.build file for the build specifications, each proyect and each module has its own file. In Android studio those specifications are not needed to be added in your manifest file.